# Button Value Not Changing when Text Field Isn't Empty

Tags: php, html

Having a small issue getting my submit button to change the value when the php variable isn't empty. So the way I have it set up is that when the button "GO" is pressed it will set the value of the text field to "1234567890" meaning it is no longer empty. Now when the page first loads the text field will be empty and the button should say "GO" once pressed the text field value will change and the button should now say "REFRESH" however it stays saying "GO" can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks.

PHP

```
<?
if (!$HostKey){
    $HostBtn = 'GO';
}
else{
    $HostBtn = 'REFRESH';
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    if (isset($_POST['Go'])) {

            $HostKey = "123567890";

        }
    }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="Home.php" method="post">
    <p><strong>HOST:</strong>
    <input name="Host" id="Host" type="text" value="<? echo $HostKey; ?>" maxlength="10" disabled>
    <input name="Go" id="Go" type="submit" value="<? echo $HostBtn; ?>"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you suggest I combat this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is a logical one, as `$HostKey` isn't defined prior to you doing your check - so `$HostKey` is null. You define it *after* that. Then, because the variable is effectively null, when you apply the not-operator `!`, that condition is *always* true.

You should refactor your code to check if the form was submitted, and define the value of the variable based on that instead. All you need in PHP would be

```
$HostBtn = isset($_POST['Go']) ? 'REFRESH' : 'GO';
$HostKey = isset($_POST['Go']) ? 123567890 : '';
```

This would also fix the "*Undefined variable...*" notices you *should* have been getting if you enabled error-reporting,

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Which should be enabled while in development. In a live environment, you shouldn't display the actual errors though - but its fine to do that under development.

Comment: Thanks for you help and clearing up this issue, this might be me but are you missing a bracket `isset($_POST['Go']`

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like :

```
<?

    if (isset($_POST['Go'])) {

            $HostKey = "123567890";
            $HostBtn= "REFRESH";

}else{
        $HostKey="";
        $HostBtn="GO";
}


?>
```